# How to make sure that lastrequest is successful and proceed to next

Tags: http, request, jmeter, token

Scenario is:
SIGNUP, which will be used further for login and other scenarios.

Check if last request is successful and get Token to proceed further with login and purchase?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [If Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/six-tips-for-jmeter-if-controller-usage) with the following condition:

```
${JMeterThread.last_sample_ok}
```

Put the [Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#samplers)(s) you would like to be executed conditionally as the If Controller's child(ren) and they will be executed only if the condition is met.

[image: JMeter If Controller Last Sampler OK]

Where `${JMeterThread.last_sample_ok}` is a [pre-defined JMeter variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#predefinedvars) holding the result of previous sampler execution, it is `true` if previous sampler was successful and `false` otherwise.